# OpenGL MSAA in 2 different ways. What are the differences?

Tags: opengl, framebuffer, render-to-texture, msaa

I have been looking for OpenGL Multi Sample Anti Aliasing tutorials and I found many but I'll take 2.

They use a different way to do this. I have tested both ways and both work for my project so I can use any of them.

I use this to render my game engine scene to a texture.

**This is the 1st way:**

Create the FBO with MSAA

```
// create a texture object
glGenTextures(1, &textureId);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureId);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA8, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

// create a MSAA framebuffer object
// NOTE: All attachment images must have the same # of samples.
// Ohterwise, the framebuffer status will not be completed.
glGenFramebuffers(1, &fboMsaaId);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fboMsaaId);

// create a MSAA renderbuffer object to store color info
glGenRenderbuffers(1, &rboColorId);
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, rboColorId);
glRenderbufferStorageMultisample(GL_RENDERBUFFER, MSAA_level, GL_RGB8, width, height);
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, 0);

// create a MSAA renderbuffer object to store depth info
// NOTE: A depth renderable image should be attached the FBO for depth test.
// If we don't attach a depth renderable image to the FBO, then
// the rendering output will be corrupted because of missing depth test.
// If you also need stencil test for your rendering, then you must
// attach additional image to the stencil attachement point, too.
glGenRenderbuffers(1, &rboDepthId);
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, rboDepthId);
glRenderbufferStorageMultisample(GL_RENDERBUFFER, MSAA_level, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, width, height);
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, 0);

// attach msaa RBOs to FBO attachment points
glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_RENDERBUFFER, rboColorId);
glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, rboDepthId);


// create a normal (no MSAA) FBO to hold a render-to-texture
glGenFramebuffers(1, &fboId);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fboId);

glGenRenderbuffers(1, &rboId);
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, rboId);
glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, width, height);
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, 0);

// attach a texture to FBO color attachement point
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureId, 0);

// attach a rbo to FBO depth attachement point
glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, rboId);

//@@ disable color buffer if you don't attach any color buffer image,
//@@ for example, rendering the depth buffer only to a texture.
//@@ Otherwise, glCheckFramebufferStatus will not be complete.
//glDrawBuffer(GL_NONE);
//glReadBuffer(GL_NONE);

// check FBO status
if (glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE)
    return false;

glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
```

And when I need to draw the scene

```
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fboMsaaId);
glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
glClearColor(0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f, 1.0f);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

DrawScene();

glBindFramebuffer(GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER, fboMsaaId);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, fboId);
glBlitFramebuffer(0, 0, width, height,  // src rect
    0, 0, width, height,  // dst rect
    GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT, // buffer mask
    GL_LINEAR); // scale filter

glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
glViewport(0, 0, App->window->GetWidth(), App->window->GetHeight());
```

**The 2nd way:**

Create the FBO with MSAA

```
unsigned int framebuffer;
glGenFramebuffers(1, &framebuffer);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, framebuffer);

// create a multisampled color attachment texture
unsigned int textureColorBufferMultiSampled;
glGenTextures(1, &textureColorBufferMultiSampled);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D_MULTISAMPLE, textureColorBufferMultiSampled);
glTexImage2DMultisample(GL_TEXTURE_2D_MULTISAMPLE, 4, GL_RGB, SCR_WIDTH, SCR_HEIGHT, GL_TRUE);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D_MULTISAMPLE, 0);
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D_MULTISAMPLE, textureColorBufferMultiSampled, 0);

// create a (also multisampled) renderbuffer object for depth and stencil attachments
unsigned int rbo;
glGenRenderbuffers(1, &rbo);
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, rbo);
glRenderbufferStorageMultisample(GL_RENDERBUFFER, 4, GL_DEPTH24_STENCIL8, SCR_WIDTH, SCR_HEIGHT);
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, 0);
glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, rbo);

if (glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE)
    cout << "ERROR::FRAMEBUFFER:: Framebuffer is not complete!" << endl;
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);

// configure second post-processing framebuffer
unsigned int intermediateFBO;
glGenFramebuffers(1, &intermediateFBO);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, intermediateFBO);

// create a color attachment texture
unsigned int screenTexture;
glGenTextures(1, &screenTexture);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, screenTexture);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, SCR_WIDTH, SCR_HEIGHT, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, screenTexture, 0);  // we only need a color buffer

if (glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE)
    cout << "ERROR::FRAMEBUFFER:: Intermediate framebuffer is not complete!" << endl;
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
```

And when I need to draw the scene:

```
 glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, framebuffer);
 glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
 glClearColor(0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f, 1.0f);
 glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

 DrawScene();

  glBindFramebuffer(GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER, framebuffer);
  glBindFramebuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, intermediateFBO);
  glBlitFramebuffer(0, 0, SCR_WIDTH, SCR_HEIGHT, 0, 0, SCR_WIDTH, SCR_HEIGHT, GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT, GL_LINEAR);

  glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
  glViewport(0, 0, App->window->GetWidth(), App->window->GetHeight());
```

**Summarizing:**
1st way: Create FBO, create RBO for color and RBO for depth and use `glRenderbufferStorageMultisample(...)` to specify the MSAA level. Then create other FBO with texture for color and RBO for depth.

2nd way: Create FBO, create Texture for color and RBO for depth and using `glTexImage2DMultisample(...)` for MSAA level in the texture. Then create other FBO and a texture.

What are the differences on using one way or other? Is one better than the other?

Comment: Does your question boil down to "What is the difference between using a texture and a renderbuffer as fbo attachment?"

Comment: @BDL Yes but when using MSAA. The differences and if one way is better than the other.

Comment: The differences are the same with or without MSAA. You might want to read [this](https://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/175962-FBO-Renderbuffer-vs-Texture)

Answer (score 2):

MSAA setup in your example is actually the same in both cases. The only difference between the two methods you depicted is - different FBO attachment type. In general, you will want to attach a texture and not render buffer when you later need to use the information from that FBO for further render passes. In such a case you would plug previous render pass FBO's texture attachment into texture unit, and sample from it in the next pass shader program. [Shadow mapping](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/intermediate-tutorials/tutorial-16-shadow-mapping/) is one of such cases.

Comment: I was doing some refactoring in my engine and realized I was using MSAA render buffers as FBO attachments instead of textures. This got me thinking: Is there any benefit to using an MSAA render buffer instead of an MSAA texture? The whole idea of a render buffer is that the driver could optimize operations because you can't read from a render buffer. But if you use an MSAA render buffer, you will always want to read from it, because you need to resolve it in order to present it.